# How to run incore_macho with FIPS and IBM WL for iOS

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to run the incore_macho which has been provided by IBM Worklight.I am unable to run this script on my mac machine, can anyone please guide what are the steps in running this script, Does it require any prerequisites. Appreciate your help.

```
reference link :- http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/05_12_JSONStore_-_Encrypting_sensitive_data_with_FIPS.pdf

code link :- http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/JSONStoreEncryptingSensitiveDataWithFIPSProject.zip

Thanks
djrecker
```

Comment: What errors are you getting when you try to run the incore_macho? The steps are in the link in the pdf you have provided. Which steps were unclear? Which steps did not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to run the `incore_macho` script add an iOS environment in Worklight and then `Run As-> Xcode Project`.  You can instruct Xcode to run the script on each build by selecting the Project and adding a build phase run script.

To add a run script build phase please see:
 https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaRunScriptBuildPhase.html

In the space for the script add:
{INSTALL_PATH}/incore_macho -exe
“$CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/$EXECUTABLE_PATH”

{INSTALL_PATH} is the location where you installed the
incore_macho file.

Comment: Can you please let us know where to install the incore_macho file on mac.Also can you let me know what will be the {INSTALL_PATH} in the command above.

Comment: The documentation shows the incore_macho script under the folder iOS->fingerprint_check. You can copy the incore_macho file to any directory that Xcode can access. You could just copy it into the /user/local/bin/ directory. Thus the {INSTALL_PATH} would be "/usr/local/bin"